# Roid Private chat issue

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, chat, quickblox, quickblox-android

I am stuck creating a private create chat dialog. I am trying to create static private chat dialog for id 19.

I am getting null object reference on PrivateChatManager

```
public class ChattingFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String APP_ID = "*****";
    public static final String AUTH_KEY = "********";
    public static final String AUTH_SECRET = "*********";
    public static final String ACCOUNT_KEY = "*************";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chatting, container, false);

        QBSettings.getInstance().init(getActivity(), APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
        QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(ACCOUNT_KEY);


                loginForQuickBlox();

        QBAuth.createSession(new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession session, Bundle params) {
                                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sucess session", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error session" + errors.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

   private boolean loginForQuickBlox() {
        final QBUser user = new QBUser();
        user.setEmail("emailid@email.com");
        user.setPassword("123456789");

        QBUsers.signIn(user, new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBUser users, Bundle params) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sucess login" + users.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                /**here i have to create static dialog for chat with id 19 **/
                QBChatService chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
                QBPrivateChatManager privateChatManager = chatService.getPrivateChatManager();
                privateChatManager.createDialog(19, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBDialog>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QBDialog dialog, Bundle args) {

                    }


                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errors.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
}
```

Below is my logcat.

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.archi.intrisfeed, PID: 24211
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.quickblox.core.QBRequestCanceler com.quickblox.chat.QBPrivateChatManager.createDialog(int, com.quickblox.core.QBEntityCallback)' on a null object reference
  at com.archi.intrisfeed.fragment.ChattingFragment$3.onSuccess(ChattingFragment.java:102)
  at com.archi.intrisfeed.fragment.ChattingFragment$3.onSuccess(ChattingFragment.java:96)
  at com.quickblox.core.Query.notifySuccess(Query.java:372)
  at com.quickblox.core.Query$VersionEntityCallback.completedWithResponse(Query.java:404)
  at com.quickblox.core.Query.completedWithResponse(Query.java:277)
  at com.quickblox.core.server.HttpRequestRunnable$1.handleMessage(HttpRequestRunnable.java:42)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-18 12:55:54.181 1224-1224/? E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
```

Comment: First you need to create session after session success you have to login user.

Comment: Actually here is my code. so please guide me.
https://codeshare.io/oHPs0

Comment: Please do not provide links to code. You should post a [mcve] in your question. Then, if your app is crashing with a NullPointerException, include the logcat

Comment: @cricket_007,I agree with you.

Comment: Okay i will give you. and will remember this things for next all times. @cricket_007.

Comment: `chatService.getPrivateChatManager()` has returned you null. Please debug that.

Comment: Yes , chatService.getPrivateChatManager() gives null.@cricket_007

Comment: I am sure . i have check with also debug.  QBPrivateChatManager privateChatManager = chatService.getPrivateChatManager(); this will return null. But not getting what is the issue..@cricket_007

Answer (score 1):

you should be logged in to the chat before creating dialog (if you use QuickBlox Android SDK version 2.6.1 or older) please see [link](https://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Login_to_Chat).
From version 3.0 you can create dialog using the class QBRestChatService, details by [link](https://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Creating_dialogs_SDK_3.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try create session with quickblox from user details and then login user for chat:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        uNameStr = emailEdt.getText().toString();
        uPwdStr = passwordEdt.getText().toString();
        final QBUser user = new QBUser();
        user.setEmail(uNameStr);
        user.setPassword(uPwdStr);
        createSession(user);
     }
});
```

Session creation :

```
private void createSession(final QBUser user){
        QBAuth.createSession(user,new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession result, Bundle params) {
                user.setId(result.getUserId());
                loginForQuickBlox(user);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                createSession(user);
            }
        });
}
```

Login user :

```
private boolean loginForQuickBlox(QBUser user) {
        QBUsers.signIn(user, new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBUser users, Bundle params) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sucess login" + users.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                QBChatService chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
                QBPrivateChatManager privateChatManager = chatService.getPrivateChatManager();
                privateChatManager.createDialog(19, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBDialog>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QBDialog dialog, Bundle args) {
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errors.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return true
}
```

Comment: I have implement this code also but still getting the same above logcat. so please guide me whats going wrong ?